# Is there a name for a word pronounced the same backwards as forwards?

Tags: pronunciation

I find it very interesting that `Judge /dʒʌdʒ/` is pronounced the same backwards as forwards while it is not a palindrome. Does this phenomenon have a name?

Comment: *Judge* is not a phonetic palindrome: pronounced backward the affricates would become fricative-stop clusters.

Comment: @StoneyB According to Wikipedia's second and looser definition, it is.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You might make a case for *phonemic* palindrome; but not if you're separating /dʒ/ into 'phonetic components'.

Comment: @Stoney an Africa test is a single phoneme. So judge really only has three, so works.

Comment: I'm doubting that there is any common English word that will sound the same if recorded and then played back in reverse.

Comment: I don't get it. To me it sounds like 'Jdge' would still sound different even without the 'U'. What did I miss there, please?

Comment: Could 'church' work in a non-rhotic accent?

Answer (score 5):

It is a ***phonetic palindrome***, as defined in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_palindrome):

> - a portion of sound or phrase of speech that is identical or roughly identical when reversed.
> - Some phonetic palindromes must be mechanically reversed, involving the use of sound recording equipment or reverse tape effects. Another, more abstract type, are words that are identical to the original when separated into their phonetic components (according to a system such as the International Phonetic Alphabet) and reversed.

Some ***phonetic palindromes:*** (from the same article):

> - "crew work"/"work crew", "dry yard", "easy", "Funny enough", "Let Bob tell", "new moon", "selfless", "Sorry, Ross", "Talk, Scott", "to boot", "top spot" (also a regular palindrome), "Y'all lie", "You're caught. Talk, Roy", and "You're damn mad, Roy".

Comment: @ffledgling 'radar' is a palindrome, but not a phonetic one.

Comment: @Glorfindel I was under the impression a phonetic palindrome is a word that sounds the same when pronounced as it would be read backwards. Else, I stand corrected.

Comment: I don't find the "crew work", "dry yard", "new moon", "Talk, Scott" or "Y'all lie" examples are phonetic palindromes; perhaps they require a particular accent (including rhoticism).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're right, deleted.